# Error: The BitBucket backend needs a "repo" in the backend configuration

Tags: git, bitbucket, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I have deployed a Gatsby site to Netlify and am trying to get Netlify CMS working on it.The source code is on BitBucket and the site itself loads fine from the URL provided by the Netlify deploy.

However, when I try to load the CMS via `/admin` I get the following Error Message:

[image]

I have followed instructions from various pages such as the guide [here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site) to troubleshoot the problem without any success. I have also followed [this guide](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/bitbucket-backend) specifically for Bit Bucket back-end configuration but nothing has worked so far.

As part of the set up I have tried the two available links to the `netlify-cms.js` script in my `static/admin/index.html` file, neither of which fix the problem.As far as I am aware I have set up `OAuth` correctly in BitBucket and have applied the repo information correctly in the Netlify CMS `config.yml`.

The error message doesn't give many pointers to what the problem can be and I have run out of ideas.Any guidance on what may be causing this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the relevant portion of your config.yml i.e `backend` ?

Comment: @Derek Nguyen Thanks for the response.After some more troubleshooting,I found that it was a formatting problem with the `config.yml` file. I recommend anyone getting this error to try an online yml formatter(easily found Googling).If all the configuration details are correct it is very likely a formatting issue.